# Separate div for each element

Tags: html

Having trouble separating my divs.  I like to have a a layout as nav->header->jqueryslider->bodytext->navfooter.  Do I create divs with ids and use css to style the positions?

Comment: what do you mean `Do I create divs with ids and use css to style the positions?` use an approach that suits your coding style . personally i use classes

Comment: Please include the HTML and CSS that you've got so far here.

Comment: @Mr.coder ids and classes are meant to be used for different purposes, not simply as a matter of personal coding style

Comment: You don't need to create wrapper divs to style your elements. You can style them directly

Comment: @Fo. i know that but it didn't give me any problems.What's the difference between id's and classes any way

Comment: @Mr.coder there's lots out there on the topic https://www.google.com/search?q=when+to+use+classes+and+ids+cs&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=c22PU4GSMafP8gf6hYDwAQ#channel=fflb&q=when+to+use+classes+and+ids+css&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&safe=off&spell=1

Comment: @Fo.: AFAIK there are only two meaningful differences between ids and classes: ids are required to be unique and they can be used as fragment identifiers. In terms of use for styling and scripting, there is a huge amount of overlap.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use divs with ids and css to style the positions.

```
<div id='nav'></div>
<div id='header'></div>
<div id='jqueryslider'></div>
<div id='bodytext'></div>
<div id='navfooter'></div>
```